# SQL Query Access - Displaying records till the end of September

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm unsure how to display records till the end of September.

Here is my code so far that seems to fail as the error "Data Type mismatch in criteria expression".

```
SELECT Month(InvoiceDate) AS IncomeMonth, Sum(TotalPrice) AS Income
FROM INVOICE
WHERE InvoiceDate <= '30/9/2018'
GROUP BY Month(InvoiceDate);
```

Sample Data:

```
InvoiceDate | TotalPrice
  05/11/18  |    $200
  05/04/18  |    $100
  05/05/18  |    $150
  05/03/18  |    $120
  05/07/18  |    $100
```

Expected Output Query Result:

```
IncomeMonth | Income
         4  |    $100 
         6  |    $150
         3  |    $120
         7  |    $100
         3  |    $120
         7  |    $100
```

Comment: provide sample data and expected output

Comment: I've provided some sample data and expected output

Comment: my bad on my behalf, forgot to add what the errors says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably wish to run a similar query next month, make it dynamic:

```
SELECT 
    Month(InvoiceDate) AS IncomeMonth, Sum(TotalPrice) AS Income
FROM 
    INVOICE
WHERE 
    InvoiceDate < DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)
GROUP BY 
    Month(InvoiceDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

it is best to use a year, month, day format for dates

```
SELECT Month(InvoiceDate) AS IncomeMonth, Sum(TotalPrice) AS Income
FROM INVOICE
WHERE InvoiceDate <= #2018/09/30#
GROUP BY Month(InvoiceDate);
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code where it missing the ' at the end of the date, but even with it fixed it says "Data Type mismatch in criteria expression"

Comment: Ah! Thank you @fa06 it's successful!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use format stortime if yo have conditon month september